# i want to make javascript wait until a variable is true then continue EDIT: i did it

Tags: javascript

i dont know how to do it and it confuses me

i tried changing a variable value every millisecond and set a timeout of what the variable value was but it was too laggy
it needs to wait until a variable is true then continue
so basicly

```
    function timer() {
    setTimeout(() => {
    tick = true
    }, 950)
    setTimeout(() => {
    tick = false
    }, 50)
    timer();
    }
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 90) {
            *code*
            *sleep, until(tick == true)*
            *code*
        }
    })
```

Comment: can you elaborate the question please

Comment: only execute code if the variable is true and if it isnt true then wait until its true

Comment: what changes the variable? maybe you could use an observer

Comment: if it helps and you're doing an async operation, you could use an await. The JS thread would wait till your operation succeeds and then continue.

Comment: doesnt this change the variable

function timer() {
setTimeout(() => {
tick = true
}, 950)
setTimeout(() => {
    tick = false
}, 50)
timer();
}

Comment: how would i use async like that

Answer (score 0):

You can use await Promise to add sleep between your code

```
await new Promise((res,rej)=>{
      setTimeout(()=>res(),3000) // set time in milliseconds
  })
```

Comment: where does the code go? also i want it to only execute if a variable is true and if it isnt true, then wait until its true

Comment: replace my code with "            *sleep, until(tick == true)*"